# How to set the title of the tab in Terminal.app to the remote server I'm logged in to

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, terminal.app

I use one Mac to do work on several others.

What I'd like to do is find a way to programmatically set the title of a Terminal.app tab to the name of the server I'm ssh-ed into, so I can determine at a glance which tab I want to jump to to check on a particular server.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, this is an easy way to do it:

```
echo -n -e "\033]0;Superuser.com rules\007"
```

Just change "SuperUser.com rules" to whatever you would like to title the session.

To capture the host name and post it to the title you could run something like this

```
name=`hostname`;echo -n -e "\033]0;$name\007"
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.

Comment: This is awesome and works great. Is there a way to make this happy automatically upon launching Terminal and/or changing hosts?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do just this the other day and I came up with the following result:

put this in your .bash_profile / .bashrc file:

```
function tabname { printf "\e]1;$1\a"; }
function winname { printf "\e]2;$1\a"; }
function ssh() { echo "$@" | tabname `sed -E 's/(.*@)?([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)(.*)/\2/'`; /usr/bin/ssh "$@"; tabname; }
```

[Automatically Changing Terminal.app Tab Names when using SSH](http://fledglingpolymath.tumblr.com/post/38536546693/automatically-changing-terminal-app-tab-names-when)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It uses a regular expression to pull out just the hostname. I'm only just learning regexes so anyone feel free to post a better solution if you can do it better.

Comment: printf has an issue when the title contains `%` characters